# Do readers of the password-management tag want a new community?

Tags: discussion

Over in area51 a debate is going on about this:

https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21958/why-a-proposal-for-identity-access-management-makes-sense

If you read the [password-management](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/password-management) tag here on SF, could you weigh in on the discussion?

Comment: Afaik most of their questions would be ontopic on Security and also on SU. But if they are ontopic here, they won't be moved there. If not... well, it is a longer question.

Comment: peterh i love this comment! Can you repeat it in the area51 discuss area?

Comment: Way to narrow a subject with too much overlap with existing SE sites IMO.

Answer (score 3):

No!  Not even a bit!

The IdM topic in general lies firmly within system administration, and those questions are welcome here.

I don't see very many of them (so I don't know how an area 51 proposal would ever net enough interest to advance), but I know there are several experts in the field here including me.